# Change both menu width for ionic side menu

Tags: css, ionic-framework

I have left and right ionic side menu, which i want to change both the menu width. I have successfully change the left menu width as shown below but i am not sure how to change the right menu width. Currently, the left menu width change but when right menu is being toggle, the right menu content is distorted.

```
.menu.menu-left{
    width: calc(100% - 70px) !important;
}
.menu-open .menu-content{
    transform: translate3d(calc(100% - 70px), 0px, 0px) !important;
}
```

[Codepen Link](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/dpKbAN)

Answer (score 5):

Just add the "menu-width" in `variables.scss`

```
$menu-width: 200px;
```

Comment: Not working in Ionic5 any idea how to set a custom width for the side menu in Ionic5?

Answer (score 3):

Use a class name to change the width of the side menu.

```
<ion-menu class="custom" side="end" menuId="first">
</ion-menu>
```

In CSS you can use like below.

```
.custom {
  --width: 500px;
}
```

Comment: Anyone been able to get this to work with --max-width?  Just --width seems to be working though, and can use a css expression with it like --width: max(90vw, 500px) to good effect

Comment: Px is good but the percentage is better for every size of the device.

Answer (score 1):

For Ionic5 and above projects, we can overwrite the side panel's CSS like below to make it customized as per requirements.

```
ion-split-pane {
  --side-max-width: 18%;
  --side-min-width: 270px;
}
```

Put this class where you implemented your menu so it will overwrite existing CSS with this.

Answer (score 0):

According to [this](https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/can-i-change-the-width-of-side-menu-with-css/11842) just add `width` attribute in `ion-side-menu` element.

Ionic docs for sidemenu is [here](http://ionicframework.com/docs/api/directive/ionSideMenu/)

```
<ion-side-menu
       side="left"
       width="500">
</ion-side-menu>
```

Comment: It does not work. Changing `width` attribute only changes the swipe position of the side menu but the `side-menu-content` width still remain the same. The width attribute is part of the side-menu so that it knows how far to translate on swipe.
Even if you did change it with css, the side-menu directive would still use the default value of 275.

Answer (score 0):

As people gave their answer I wish to give it mine too.

PX is good but if we add width in percentage then its works with every device.
add this scss on your page.scss file

```
ion-menu {
  --width: 83%;
}
```

And the HTML does not need to give a class name or anything, you can give it if you want.

```
<ion-menu contentId="main-content" type="overlay"></ion-menu>
```

Answer (score 0):

Put it inside :root on variables.scss

e.g.

```
<ion-menu menuId="mainMenu" class="mainMenu">
...
</ion-menu>
```

and set it like

```
:root {

  .mainMenu {
    --width: 100vw;
  }

  or

  ion-menu {
    --width: 100vw;
  }

}
```